# javascript variable scope across functions jQuery involved

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what i cannot get to work - in mouseMove this.mouseX is undefined. I need the mouseX and mouseY (e.pageX in code) from mousemove event.

```
function myClass () {
    var mouseX=x;
    var mouseY=y;
    $(document).mousemove(this.mouseMove);
}
myClass.prototype.mouseMove = function(e){
    this.mouseX=e.pageX;//not a good idea but you can alert this
}
var a=new myClass();
```

Can i get that event passed to the supposed class instance or there is no way to get it done?

I should also mention i am trying to avoid global scope variables here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Two</del> three things:

`var mouseX` only declares a variable *local to the myClass function*. You have to declare a property of the instance with `this.mouseX` (`this` refers to the current instance):

```
function myClass () {
    this.mouseX=x;  // where do x and y come from?
    this.mouseY=y;
    //...
}
```

Secondly, make sure you pass `x` and `y` as parameters to the constructor. Otherwise you will get an error (if they are not defined in higher scope, but that does not seem useful to me).

Thirdly, if you just pass `this.mouseMove` as event handler, inside the event handler, `this` will refer to `window` and not to the `myClass` instance. Use [**`$.proxy`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to set the context of the callback explicitly:

```
function myClass(x, y) {
    this.mouseX=x;
    this.mouseY=y;
    $(document).mousemove($.proxy(this.mouseMove, this));
}
```

---

I suggest to read [*MDC - Working with objects*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: first two things are just mistakes in my copy-paste-erase example making process, third one is what i was looking for, ty :D

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a method like `this.mouseMove` as a callback function, it's no longer tied to the instance - so `this` will be the global object. To fix the scope, you can pass the instance in a closure, like so:

```
function myClass (x,y) {
    var mouseX=x;
    var mouseY=y;
    var that = this;
    $(document).mousemove(function() { that.mouseMove() });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function myClass (x,y) {
    var mouseX=x;
    var mouseY=y;
    var $this = this;

    $(document).mousemove(function(){$this.mouseMove()});
}
myClass.prototype.mouseMove = function(e){
    this.mouseX=e.pageX;//not a good idea but you can alert this
}
var a=new myClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myClass () {
    this.mouseX=x;
    this.mouseY=y;
    $(document).mousemove(this.mouseMove);
}
myClass.prototype.mouseMove = function(e){
    this.mouseX=e.pageX;//not a good idea but you can alert this
}
var a=new myClass();
```

You need to use the this keyword and not var to instantiate in the constructor